# Instance Variable Changing

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I would like to make movement of a square with only using Instance Variable. I'm having troubles this is my code :

I have one for Variables.JAVA for Variables :

```
public class Variables {
       String name;
       int Playerx;
       int Playery;
       int Playerw;
       int Playerh;
 }
```

and one where it is the main but doesn't change the variables above. (simplified)

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {

       while (true) {
          Variables P = new Variables(){
                synchronized (c) {
                c.clear();
                first_level();
                P.Playerx = 50;
                P.Playery = 50;
                P.Playerw = 100;
                P.Playerh = 100;

                c.drawRect(P.Playerx, P.Playery, P.Playerw, P.Playerh);

                }

                Thread.sleep(25);

                // Controls
                if (c.isKeyDown(Console.VK_UP)) {
                    P.Playery -= 10;

                }
                else if (c.isKeyDown(Console.VK_DOWN)) {
                    P.Playery += 10;
                }
                else if (c.isKeyDown(Console.VK_LEFT)) {
                    P.Playerx -= 10;
                }

                else if (c.isKeyDown(Console.VK_DOWN)) {
                    P.Playery += 10;

                }
            }
```

The `P.Player(x,y,w,h)` don't change?

How can this be solved?

Comment: What GUI library are you using? Swing? Processing? Other? You do know that you're creating a new Variable instance with each iteration of your while loop, right? Why do you have a synchronized block when there doesn't appear to be any multi-threading going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the defaults in every iteration, your code is  synchronic and therefore responding to the keys is done after you draw, and in the next iteration you are overriding the values again so you will never see any changes.
In addition you instantiate a new P object every time and not keeping the previous instances alive, therefore they are GC.